# Why cannot set output folder to WEB-INF/classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'm assigning specific output folders to each source folder in the project, but Eclipse complains about `WEB-INF/classes` as an output folder.

The error message is :

> Source folder "wapi" in project "Web6020" cannot output to library "WEB-INF/classes"

I am not sure whether it's a legal output folder or if `Eclipse` is trying to enforce some good practice.

Manually copying the output to my intended destination is the only workaround I found so far.

Comment: You using any build system, ant ore gradle?

Comment: I am not using any build system, as far as I know..

Comment: I don't know the problem because not using eclipse but if you do not resolve the problem I think is better using a system construction like gradle for creating the web dir executive automatized. this is not a solution but is a way to get around this

Comment: Is this `WEB-INF/classes` in the `Web6020` project?

Comment: @nitind I just found that the Project Explorer in `Eclipse` shows a `classes` subfolder under `WEB-INF` but there is no such folder in the project files on the filesystem. Looking at the `classes` properties, I see that is is a virtual folder.

Comment: There is the `C:\Users\mdagl\eclipse-workspace\Web6020\WebClient\WEB-INF` which is shown in the properties of the `WEB-INF` in the project and there is a `C:\Web6020\WebClient\WEB-INF` which really contains the `classes` subforlder in the file system, and that is where I want to have my compiled java files